# Mongorestore writing to MongoDB datafiles

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

MongoDB documentation has the following line. What do they mean when they say, mongorestore can directly write to MongoDB data files without an active mongod? Does it mean it can write even if a mongod instance is not ready and reachable, or, is there something called inactive mongod instance. I am finding it difficult to understand. Can someone explain me this?

> mongorestore can write data to either mongod or mongos instances, in addition to writing directly to MongoDB data files without an active mongod.

Comment: Can you include the documentation url where you found this reference? I suspect this is referring to an older version of `mongorestore` (prior to 3.0) where there was a `--dbpath` option to write directly to files in the MMAP storage format. Current versions of `mongorestore` require a running MongoDB deployment to restore data into.

Comment: [link](http://www.dba86.com/docs/mongo/2.4/reference/program/mongorestore.html) You are absolutely right on the version. I didn't notice the version on the docs page--clicked on the link and landed there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to v3.x `mongorestore` could be configured to write directly to data files rather than writing into data files *via* `mongod`.

The term "data files" here refers to the contents of a `dbpath` directory so, by specifying `--dbpath` you could tell `mongorestore` to attach to the data files in that directory and insert data into those files without having to go through a `mongod` instance.

Comment: Thank you, @glytching ! Before coming here for answers, I tried to do mongorestore without running a mongod process. It just spit the error and stopped as expected. I went ahead and then looked into the data files under the dbpath--ofcourse nothing was found. All I had learnt recently is that a mongo shell can be run without connecting to a database using --nodb, and not write anything. This was contradicting my understanding. Thank you guys for pointing out the version and explaining it!